# Passing multiple arguments to Javascript via port

Tags: elm

I need to pass a few parameters to Javascript, but for a strange reason it does not compile. I started with:

```
port check : String -> Cmd msg
```

this works fine (as taken directly from [JavaScript Interop](http://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html)). But when I am adding another parameter

```
port check : Int -> String -> Cmd msg
```

I am getting

> 1| port check : Int -> String -> Cmd msg
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> You are saying it should be:
>
> ```
> Int -> String -> Platform.Cmd.Cmd msg
> ```
>
> But you need to use the particular format described here:
>   http://guide.elm-lang.org/effect_managers/

I solved this simply by reducing arguments back to one

```
type alias Bundle = (Int, String)
port check : Bundle -> Cmd msg
```

but that would be cleaner if I could simply do

```
app.ports.check.subscribe(function(arg1, arg2) {
});
```

Why it doesn't compile?

Comment: I don't know for certain but in earlier Elm versions, ports took a Signal of (a Signal.map of) a model, so were used with records (JS objects). Perhaps, as a result, thay have always only passed a single argument

Answer (score 17):

`port`s can only have one parameter. If you need to pass multiple parameters then your only options are to pass a tuple (like you did with `Bundle`) or a record.

On the js side, you'll have to take one parameter but you can destructure it after with whatever var names you want

```
app.ports.check.subscribe(function(arg) {
  var [arg1, arg2] = arg;
});
```

If you're using ES6, then you do have some nicer options for destructuring in the function params if you use a record [like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Pulling_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter):

```
app.ports.check.subscribe(function({arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2}) {
});
```

Comment: I noticed that only one parameter gets accepted, but why? On Javascript side I already "deserialized" the arguments like you suggested, but I wonder why Elm cannot accept more parameters. It look like a bug to me. Clearly an inconsistency.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. Isn't that just because the type Cmd takes one parameter? http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/Platform-Cmd#Cmd

Comment: @RafałCieślak ok. I think I understand now how it works. Thanks. Still I am not sure if this is the correct behavior. The need for wrapping and unwrapping makes me uncomfortable.

Answer (score 8):

I noticed you don't really have to "decode" much on the Javascript side. So, you can package your single parameter up as a nice type in ELM.

Do something like this in your elm:

```
type alias MyObject = 
  { name: String 
  , displayDate: String
  , subTitle: String
  , hashTag: String
  }

port check : MyObject -> Cmd msg
```

Then in the javascript you can just do this:

```
app.ports.check.subscribe(function(myObject) {
            alert( myObject.name);
            alert( myObject.displayDate);
            alert( myObject.subTitle);
            alert( myObject.hashTag);
        });
```